# Dispatcher-servlet.xml - not mandatory?

Tags: spring-3

I am working on an assignment that is already built to some extent. It is a Spring 3.0 project with Spring Integration and Spring MVC. I see that in web.xml, the  is defined and the name is associated to the DispatcherServlet class. But in /web-inf/ I don't see the Dispatcher-servlet.xml

when I looked at the spring documentation, I read that the Dispatcher-servlet.xml is mandatory.

The app is working fine. The jsp is fetched and the flow is as expected.But without the Dispatcher-servlet.xml, how is it working? Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Jan.

Answer (score 1):

Eg: here is my web.xml definition. Over here my dispatcherservlet name is springController-servlet.xml which is placed in the web-inf folder.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Check yours and revert back. Spring requires a dispatcher servlet file.